# Когда printf возвращает ошибку

Tags: c, gcc

В документации к семейству функций `printf()` написано:

> Если случилась ошибка вывода, то возвратится отрицательное значение.

Где-то еще видел что-то вроде:

> При ошибке кодирования возвращается -1

Вопросы: можете привести пример, когда `snprintf()` вернет `-1`, при условии что буфера для записи достаточно? Что это за ошибки вывода/кодирования такие?

---

PS: столкнулся предположительно c такой ситуацией на одной из виртуалок:

```
int ret = snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "\xad");  // ret == -1
```

но воспроизвести не получается.

Comment: Если дело происходит под Linux, попробуйте воспользоваться [explain_snprintf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/explain_snprintf) для получения сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: Вы же сами написали: документация относится к **семейству** функций `printf`. Отдельно к `snprintf` данное утверждение не относится.

Comment: @AnT, какое именно утверждение не относится? Все таки у меня в боевом коде именно `snprintf` возвращал -1, поэтому я попросил пример с snprintf. Если приведете пример с `printf`, это было бы тоже очень здорово.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [man snprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) в секции **Return value** написано:

> "If an output error is encountered, a negative value is returned".

Я бы сказал, что сейчас возврат -1 может относиться к printf/fprintf/vfprintf/..., но не к семейству snprintf().

Однако, там же в секции NOTES написано, для snprintf/vsnprintf

> "Until glibc 2.0.6 they would return -1 when the output was
>   truncated."

Видимо, цитата, которую вы где-то видели относится именно к версиям glibc до 2.0.6

---

P.S.

Дополнительный эксперимент (в glibc 2.27) показал, что как `snprintf()`, так и `printf()` (и вероятно все остальные функции этого семейства) возвращают -1 если в функцию передать NULL вместо *строки формата*.

При этом `errno == EINVAL`, что означает `"Invalid argument"`.

Comment: Но я "своими глазами" видел, как `snprintf` возвращал -1 :)

Comment: glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.x86_64

Comment: Возможно, это платформозависимое поведение, но в общем меня бы устроил любой пример, пусть даже он был бы специфичный для определенного компилятора/платформы/окружения.

Comment: @o2gy, OK, вы сподвигли меня на эксперименты и я получил -1 и от snprintf и printf. / ERRNO = EINVAL ("`Invalid argument`"  число 22) если строка формата NULL (getconf GNU_LIBC_VERSION
glibc 2.27)

Comment: Спасибо, помечаю ответ как верный, т.к. формально пример действительно приведен.

Comment: Однако, гештальт не закрыт. У меня воспроизводится ошибка следующим кодом: `snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%.*s", 1, "\xad");`. НО! Есть apache, работающий с mod_perl. Есть сишная библиотека, которая вызывается из перла. Т.е. дергаем http-конец, апач дергает перл, перл дергает сишную либу, `snprintf` возвращает -1.

Comment: Если я на той же виртуалке пишу такой же код в main.c, компиляю примерно так же и запускаю ./a.out, то тот же самый `snprintf` возвращает 1 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @o2gy, вряд ли у меня будет время всерьез разобраться с апачем. Может стоит попатчить ту либу с snprintf в ней или все можно решить через  LD_LIBRARY_PATH или в конце-концов поправить в cбойном месте перл (написав свое копирование в этом месте вместо snprintf() (согласитесь, в таком виде, как вы его показали это попахивает обычной ленью -)))